# jQuery Events params through chain

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-events

```
function first(a){
  if (a == 'a'){
    return false;
  }
}

function second(){
  return 'a';
}

$('.c').click(first).click(second);
```

How to send message to other chained events? Or stop others from one?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop next clicks from happening, you can use the [stopImmediatePropagation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.stopImmediatePropagation.28.29) method:

```
$("p").click(function(event){
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
$("p").click(function(event){
  // This function won't be executed
});
```

To send messages among callbacks, I don't know any other way than using external variables.

Actually, this is almost a dupe of [jQuery Multiple Event Handlers - How to Cancel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652495/jquery-multiple-event-handlers-how-to-cancel)...