# clicking on div fires binding for $('body').click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a div, I want to set it so that when I click on something else, it would hide the div.

So I did

```
$('body').click(function(){
    if(loginOpened)
    {
        $('#loginWindow').animate({
            'width':'0px',
            'height':'0px'
        },"fast");
    }
    loginOpened=false;
});
```

However, even when I click in the div itself the event is fired, is there anyway to prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can stop it using

`e.stopPropagation();` if there is a click event bound to the `<div />` tag.

See **[event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)**

> Prevents the event from bubbling up
>   the DOM tree, preventing any parent
>   handlers from being notified of the
>   event.

Otherwise you can check the target of the event inside the body click. Check whether `event.target` is the same as your div.

See **[event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)**

Answer (score 2):

Just check the event.target.   If the element that triggered the event is your div do not execute the code.

```
$('body').click(function(evt){
    evt = evt || window.event
    if ($(evt.target) != $('#loginWindow')) {
      if(loginOpened)
      {
          $('#loginWindow').animate({
              'width':'0px',
              'height':'0px'
          },"fast");
      }
      loginOpened=false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can we compare `$(evt.target)` with `$('#loginWindow')`? Will the two objects be the same?

Comment: @rahul ..Yes they should be.  but even if they are not you can comparre $(evt.target).attr('id') with "loginWindow" ... the id property should match.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but of course Microsoft and the rest of the world came to different conclusions about how to do it.  This site gives a good clear rundown of what's needed: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html .

I don't use jQuery but the jQuery way appears to be `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` as seen in this question: [jQuery Multiple Event Handlers - How to Cancel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652495/jquery-multiple-event-handlers-how-to-cancel) .

Answer (score 0):

A couple of changes from John's code:

```
$('body').click(function(ev){
    // jQuery means never having to say "window.event"!
    // Also, code's cleaner and faster if you don't branch, 
    // and choose simple breaks over more complex ones
    if(!loginOpened) return;
    // Lastly, compare using the DOM element; 
    // jQuery objects never compare as the "same"*
    if (ev.target == $('#loginWindow').get(0)) return;  
    $('#loginWindow').animate({
        'width':'0px',
        'height':'0px'
    },"fast");
    loginOpened=false;
});
```

If trapping it in the body event doesn't work for you, you *can* just add a simple event handler to the div:

```
$('#loginWindow').click(function (ev) { ev.stopPropagation(); });
```

I was going to say return false, but that would prevent other things from firing off the div.  stopPropagation just keeps the event from bubbling outward.

I could be really picky, of course...

```
//Delegation via the document element permits you to bind the event before
// the DOM is complete; no flashes of unbehaviored content
$(document).delegate('body', 'click', function(ev){
    //You only have one instance of an id per page, right?
    if(!loginOpened || ev.target.id == 'loginWindow') return;
    //quotes and px?  not necessary.  This isn't json, and jQ's smart
    $('#loginWindow').animate({width:0,height:0},"fast");
    loginOpened=false;
});
```

* Don't believe me?  Try:

```
jQuery('#notify-container') == jQuery('#notify-container')
```

Then try

```
jQuery('#notify-container').get(0) == jQuery('#notify-container').get(0)
```