# how to limit a click event applied to the <body> from executing on a jquery datatable in the body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have animated datatables which slide in from the left when their hyperlink is clicked.  And when the user is done reading the contents of the visible datatable, I applied the following code to allow the user to click anywhere else to park the table away and proceed with viewing.  I used jQuery code for attaching the click event...

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready( function () {$('.dtable').dataTable( {"sDom": 'rt',"sScrollY":"200px", "bPaginate":false, "bFilter":false} );**$('body').click(function() {parkDataTables();});})
</script>
```

Unfortunately, clicking on the datatable itself parks it.  And I don't want that behavior.  Maybe someone has an idea on how to block this click event from firing on the surface of the datatable...

Many thanks

Dennis

Comment: Same problem with accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956565/clicking-on-div-fires-binding-for-body-click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it with

```
$('.dtable').click(function(){return false;});
```

The problem is that when you click on the table, the event goes **into the table first** and **then** it propagates to the parents (and finally to the `body`, when the `parkDataTables` is catched).

You could also use `stopPropagation` instead ( http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/ ), because with the `return false` you also stop the default click behavior on the table.

```
$('.dtable').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Maybe you could check this page to see this last difference: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: This one worked great and it was easy to implement.  Many thanks for the help!  Had to add the DIV to the table..
               $('.dtable').click(function(event){event.stopPropagation()});
            $('.ctnr').click(function(event){event.stopPropagation()});

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using body as the selector you could use

```
$('body').children().not('.dtable')
```

So you would get

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready( 
  function () {
   $('.dtable').dataTable( {"sDom": 'rt',"sScrollY":"200px", "bPaginate":false, "bFilter":false} );
$('body').children().not('.dtable').click(function() {
  parkDataTables();
 });})
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, i've used the NOT selector for something like this before, it should work very well.

Comment: This will only work if your `dtable` is an immediate child of the body.

Comment: Sounds right, but it still parks.  Could it be that the DIV of the dTable is responding?

Comment: I implemented @Renato's 2nd suggestion.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: no problem, as a side note, you could use $('body').find('*').not('.dtable'). Nice alternative @Renato :)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery propagates the function up through every parent. In order to stop the propagation, you must "return false;".

In your case, you want to try:

```
> $('body').click(function() { if $(this).hasClass('dtable'){return
> false;}) if $(this).hasClass('body'){park}
```

And give your body a class of 'body' to make it selectable.

Comment: Think it is better to get the selector right in the first place, as theoretically he now has two click events on the dtable class

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Because of the added if statements I went with @Renato's second suggestion.  It worked.  Many thanks for your help.